# How do I save ArrayLists with different names in a while loop?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm kinda stuck in a java project. I have this issue and i don't know how to work this out.

Basically i create a robot wich go from object to object listing them. Objects don't move but robots (agents in my code) do.

Some of the variables i use come from the FinalProject Class wich is my main class.

I create a matrix of ArrayLists as my world and i want to add objects and agents to it. They both henerit from the class Entity. My problem is I dont know how to name them differently as I add them to the matrix. Here's my World class:

```
package finalproject;
import java.util.*;

public class World {
protected int cord_x , cord_y , agent_num , object_num , numero_x , numero_y, conta = 1, i = 0;
protected String op, nome;
protected String [] tipos;

public World (int cord_x, int cord_y, int agent_num, int object_num , String op){
    this.cord_x = cord_x;
    this.cord_y = cord_y;
    this.agent_num = agent_num;
    this.object_num = object_num;
    this.op = op;
    ArrayList<Entity>[][] mundo = (ArrayList<Entity>[][])new ArrayList<?>[cord_x][cord_y];
    if (op.equals("s")){
        gera_agent(agent_num , mundo);
        gera_object(object_num, mundo);
    }
}

private ArrayList<Entity>[][] gera_agent(int num , ArrayList<Entity>[][] mundo){
    String [] cores = {"vermelho", "azul", "verde", "preto"};
    String [] formas = {"triangulo", "quadrado", "retangulo", "losango"};
    String [] estrategias = {"random", "hamming", "closest"};
    i=0;
    while (i<num){
        int numeroY = new Random().nextInt(cord_x);
        int numeroX = new Random().nextInt(cord_y);
        int rcores = new Random().nextInt(cores.length);
        int rformas = new Random().nextInt(formas.length);
        int restrategias = new Random().nextInt(estrategias.length);

        String cor = (cores[rcores]);
        String forma = (formas[rformas]);
        String estrategia = (estrategias[restrategias]);
        nome = "Agente" + Integer.toString(conta);
        Entity nome = new Agent(nome, cor, forma, numeroX, numeroY, conta, estrategia, FinalProject.raio);
        mundo[numeroX][numeroY].add(nome);
        conta++;
        i++;
    }
    return mundo;
}

private ArrayList<Entity>[][] gera_object(int num , ArrayList<Entity>[][] mundo){
    String [] cores = {"vermelho", "azul", "verde", "preto"};
    String [] formas = {"triangulo", "quadrado", "rectangulo", "losango"};

    if (FinalProject.op1.equals("planeta")){
        tipos = new String[] {"rocha", "alien", "caratera"};
    }
    else if (FinalProject.op1.equals("catastrofe")){
        tipos =  new String []{"sobrevivente", "morto", "escombros"};
    }
    else if (FinalProject.op1.equals("domesticos")){
        tipos = new String [] {"mesa", "cadeira", "vassora"};
    }

    i=0;
    while (i<num){
        int numeroX = new Random().nextInt(cord_x);
        int numeroY = new Random().nextInt(cord_y);

        int rcores = new Random().nextInt(cores.length);
        int rformas = new Random().nextInt(formas.length);
        int rtipo;
        rtipo = new Random().nextInt(tipos.length);
        String cor = (cores[rcores]);
        String forma = (formas[rformas]);
        String tipo = (tipos[rtipo]);
        nome = "Object" + Integer.toString(conta);
        Entity nome = new Object(nome, cor, forma, numeroX, numeroY, conta, estrategia, FinalProject.raio);
        mundo[numeroX][numeroY].add(nome);
        conta++;
        i++;

    }
    return mundo;
}
```

Basically when i am doing this:  Entity nome = new Agent(nome, cor, forma, numeroX, numeroY, conta, estrategia, FinalProject.raio);
            mundo[numeroX][numeroY].add(nome); - which is stupid. Do i need to name the object i wanna add in the matrix? if i do, how do i do it?

at some point in my name i create the world using some input variables this way:

```
World mundo = new World(W_x , W_y , num_ag , num_ob , op2);
```

My Entity Class:

```
package finalproject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class  Entity {
    protected String name;
    protected String color;
    protected String shape;
    protected int xCoordenate;
    protected int yCoordenate;
    protected int id;
    public Entity (String name, String color , String shape , int xCoordenate , int yCoordenate , int id){
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.shape = shape;
        this.xCoordenate = xCoordenate;
        this.yCoordenate = yCoordenate;
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Comment: Consider providing much more detail to your question text. Your asking your question as if we intuitively understand your code and what you're trying to do, when in fact, we don't. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, thereby getting better answers.

Comment: You didn't create "a 2D ArrayList of objects", you created an ArrayList of 2D objects.

Comment: Actually, more accurately: you created a matrix (2D array) of `ArrayList`s. So, you don't have a 2D `ArrayList`, you have `cord_x`*`cord_y` `ArrayList`s.

Comment: @Francisco You probably don't really want a two-dimensional array containing `ArrayList`s as elements, but that's what you've defined. But, as mentioned, we don't really know what your intent is.

Comment: In any case, as HCFOE said, you haven't described the problem at all. Why don't this do the trick??

Comment: Please do also mention whether you know the x and y sizes of the 2D array in advance, or at what time you know them.

Comment: ok, il reformulate the question. Give me a minute

Comment: What is the actual question? What do you mean when you say 'name'?

Comment: when i create a new Entity, doing Entity [Entity name] = new Agent(nome, cor, forma, numeroX, numeroY, conta, estrategia, FinalProject.raio); i need to give that entity a name. The problem is I dont initially know how many entitys i have so i can give them proper names. I want to know a way of naming my entitys so i can add the to my world

Comment: The variable name isn't going to last unless you make it a field or something. What purpose do you have of naming them in the first place? What cases are there where an Entity's name is important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in your code is that you are not initializing the ArrayList before it's use e.g. One I have written in the snippet below:: `mundo[i][j] = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

```
     int cord_x = 6, cord_y = 5, num = 10;
     ArrayList<Integer>[][] mundo = (ArrayList<Integer>[][])
                                             new ArrayList<?>[cord_x][cord_y];
     for(int i = 0; i < cord_x; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < cord_y; j++){

             //***Instantiate the ArrayList---This is required***
             mundo[i][j] = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
             for(int k = 0; k < num; k++){
                 // Add the elements in the array list
                 mundo[i][j].add(new Integer(i+j+k)); 
             }
         }
     }

     //Check the elements
     for(int i = 0; i < cord_x; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < cord_y; j++){
             for(int k = 0; k < num; k++){
                 // prints the elements
                 System.out.println("mundo["+i+"]["+j+"]- place "
                      +k+" Element == " +mundo[i][j].get(k)); 
             }
         }
     }
```

The above snippet populates the elements the first iteration and prints them in the second as:

```
mundo[0][0]- place 0 Element == 0
mundo[0][0]- place 1 Element == 1
mundo[0][0]- place 2 Element == 2
mundo[0][0]- place 3 Element == 3
......
```

I think you can adapt two approaches in your code.

1. Before `mundo[numeroX][numeroY].add(nome);` line add a check to see initialization as below

   ```
   if(mundo[numeroX][numeroY] == null){
       mundo[numeroX][numeroY] = new ArrayList<Entity>();
   }
   ```
2. Before the while loop, you can initialize all the array list elements together by putting a initialization snippet as below:

   ```
    for(int i = 0; i < cord_x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cord_y; j++){
            mundo[i][j] = new ArrayList<Entity>(); // <-- Instantiate the ArrayList
        }
    }
   ```